# ¿Cómo agregar una imagen en un JPanel sin redimensionar?

Tags: java, netbeans

Mi problema es que quiero ponerle una imagen de fondo a un JPanel y lo hice creando una clase donde uso el paintComponent para poner la imagen y esta a su vez se ajusta al tamaño de la ventana, es decir si yo reduzco el tamaño de la ventana, la imagen tambien se reduce por lo que se ve un poco distorsionada, entonces cual seria la forma optima de poner una imagen que no se ajuste al tamaño de la ventana y se mantenga estática.

Comment: Por favor agrega un __[mcve]__ para comprender mejor tu problema.

Comment: No está muy claro lo que pides. ¿Podrias poner algunas capturas de pantalla?

Comment: @toledano, modifique la descripcion para que sea un poco mas clara, gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curate en salud poniendo sobre el `JPanel` un `JLabel` del tamaño de la imagen HD en cuestión, de las formas que ya conoces, con un `setBounds(x,y,a,b)` o los `setSize(a,b)` y `setLocation(x,y)`.

**Imagina lo siguiente:**

```
fondo.setIcon( new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/imagenes/imagen.jpeg" ) ) );
fondo.setBounds( 0, 0, fondo.getIcon().getIconWidth(), fondo.getIcon().getIconHeight() );
```

Lo anterior definitivamente te permitirá reajustar el tamaño de la ventana sin alterar las dimensiones de la imagen de fondo de la aplicación.

**Edito:**
 Si en tu caso estas haciendo uso de algún Layout Manager lógicamente puedes omitir la linea del `setBounds()` y el comportamiento será prácticamente casi el mismo, sin que la imagen pierda calidad.